# Insert row is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display my results and I am getting an error: "insertRow is not a function. Not sure how I can fix this.

**JS file:**

```
function sayHelloCallback (response) {
   var table = document.getElementById("wheel");

   for(i = 0; i < response.message.length; i++)
   {
       var row = table.insertRow(0);
       var cell = row.insertCell(0);
       cell.innerHTML = response["message"][i];
   }
}
```

**HTML File:**

```
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-64 w3-center" id="salaries">
   <h2>View Salaries</h2>
   <p id="wheel">
       <i class="fa fa-spinner w3-spin" style="font-size:64px"></i>
   </p>
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: `insertRow` is a function on a table element, not a `p` element.

Comment: you have not define your table as Table

Answer (score 3):

`insertRow` is a property of **tables**.

You are trying to call it on a **paragraph**.

If you want to add data to an arbitrary element, use `appendChild`.

Answer (score 2):

> The **HTMLTableElement.insertRow()** method inserts a new row in the table and returns a reference to the new row.

Then **[`insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)** function should be called on `HTMLTableElement`, but the elment with the id `wheel` in your sample is a paragraph `p` and not a table.

Answer (score 0):

[insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) is a [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) method. you need to call it on a table element.

**Ex:**

```js
function sayHelloCallback(response) {
    //window.alert(response.message);
    var table = document.getElementById("wheel");

    for (i = 0; i < response.message.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = response["message"][i];
    }
}

sayHelloCallback({
    message: [
        "Hello, World!"
    ]
})
```

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-64 w3-center" id="salaries">
    <h2>View Salaries</h2>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner w3-spin" style="font-size:64px"></i>
    <table id="wheel"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "insertRow is not a function," suggests that the table variable is not being recognized as an HTML table element.

```js
 <script>
        function sayHelloCallback(response) {
            var table = document.getElementById("wheel");

            for (var i = 0; i < response.message.length; i++) {
                var row = table.insertRow(-1); // Use -1 to append to the end of the table
                var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                cell.textContent = response.message[i];
            }
        }

        // Simulating response for testing
        var mockResponse = {
            message: ["Salary 1", "Salary 2", "Salary 3"]
        };

        // Call the function with a mock response
        sayHelloCallback(mockResponse);
    </script>
```